# Automating audio processing in Adobe Audition

Tags: audio, automation, audition

I need to run a predefined set of filters on WAV files using Audition. The commands themselves need to be executed on the command line; I don't have the option of using Audition's Batch processing because this is part of a production pipeline I'm building. How can I automate the process of Audition starting up, opening a file, running a set of filters, saving file and closing?

Comment: You might want to investigate Adobe's automation platform, Adobe CEP Extensions: https://elbo.in/1Cb Alternatively, you could consider something like Sox, a command line audio editing tool: http://sox.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Dmitri Nesteruk - How did you progress with this idea?